# How to add Tools dynamically in an Ext Js window?

Tags: extjs4, extjs, extjs3

I wanto to add a tool (search, help, gear, ...) in a window dynamically, like this:
http://www.rahulsingla.com/sites/default/files/content/blog/extjs/extjs-panel-add-tool.htm

**And I need to create more than one instance of UIMyWindow at the same time.**

However, I'm using Ext Designer which generates 2 files:

- MyWindow.ui.js: class declaration.
- MyWindow.js: methods implementation.

Besides Ext Designer hasn't an option Tools at design time (I didn't find).

I was adding the tool outside MyWindow.js and MyWindow.ui.js, like this:

```
var winMyWindow = new UIMyWindow({
    autoShow: 'true', 
    tools: [{
               type:'gear',
               handler: function(){
                   // Some code...
               }
    }]
});
```

But I want to put this block inside MyWindow.js. So, I did this:

```
UIMyWindow = Ext.extend(UIMyWindowUi, {
    tools: [{
               type:'gear',
               handler: function(){
                   // Some code...
               }
    }],

initComponent: function() {
   UImenuDock.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
```

If you ask me "Why not to put this code inside MyWindow.ui.js?", I would answer "because I don't want to put this code manually every time I make changes in the design file (Ext Designer)".

Well, if I open one window, it's seems work ok, but if I open a second at the same time, the tools are duplicated in the second window...

So, any idea how to add tools dynamically in MyWindow.js in this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put 'tools' into initComponent

```
UIMyWindow = Ext.extend(UIMyWindowUi, {  

initComponent: function() {
  this.tools = [{
               type:'gear',
               handler: function(){
                   // Some code...
               }
    }], 
  UImenuDock.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
```